# OracleBulkCopy in ODP.NET does not work when Oracle column name has spaces

Tags: .net, oracle, bulkinsert, odp.net, data-migration

I am using OracleBulkCopy class to move data to Oracle Server from a C# DataTable.
Things are fine as long as the column name in Oracle does not have a space in it.
(The column name in the datatable does not have any space.)

I have a column "Modified By" in the Oralce table.
When I try to map that in the column name, none of the following works:

bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("columnnameindatatable", "Modified By");
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("columnnameindatatable", "\"Modified By\""); - adding quote
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("columnnameindatatable", "MODIFIED BY"); - all caps
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("columnnameindatatable", "\"MODIFIED BY\""); - all caps; adding quote

I am getting either "Modified By: Invalid identifier" or the famous "Column mapping is invalid" error.

Comment: how exactly is the column name writte in all_tab_columns ? You normally need to specify exactly so, enclosed in double quotes ("), in same case.

Comment: It appears as _Modified By_  in the all_tab_columns, which I had tried already but not fruitful.

Comment: maybe an Oracle trace can show what really happens? Maybe it is a restriction of odp.net .... Not familiar with it. Spaces and camelcase in Oracle table/column names is not often done. Often leads to complications.